# How to overwrite the parent width with position absolute?

Tags: html, css

I am new html css,I am pretty confused with notification bar this should be responsive to adopt full screen when it is in mobile.But I tried it is not expanding .
[image]

But for me it is not working

HTML Markup

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/InterestPage.css">




</head>
<body>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->

<header>
    <div class="innerwrapper">
        <h1><a href="#">Feel Hunt</a></h1>
        <div class="otherOptions">

            <div class="notificationdiv">
             <div class="notifyCoun">
                 <p>3</p>
             </div>
                <svg style="enable-background:new 0 0 48 48;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 48 48" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><style type="text/css">
    .st0{display:none;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#303030;stroke-width:0.7;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#303030;}
</style><g class="st0" id="Padding__x26__Artboard"/><g id="Icons"><g><path class="st1" d="M12.44998,29.25c0.4714-1.86041,0.98683-3.71044,1.39399-5.58655    c0.20076-0.92508,0.37522-1.85624,0.50479-2.79409c0.12749-0.92277,0.12761-1.86938,0.32255-2.78069    c0.17715-0.82819,0.41986-1.62416,0.79385-2.38678c0.72808-1.48468,1.84795-2.76857,3.21698-3.69551    c1.54611-1.04685,3.39019-1.61638,5.25786-1.61638c2.6,0,4.96,1.06,6.66999,2.76999    c1.1685,1.1685,1.95078,2.64423,2.40368,4.22483c0.48483,1.69205,0.49984,3.44094,0.81387,5.16177    c0.41544,2.27656,1.13475,4.46739,1.71247,6.7034"/><path class="st1" d="M36.75998,35.78003H11.24002c-0.35004,0-0.60004-0.33002-0.5-0.67004L12.44998,29.25h23.09003    l1.71997,5.85999C37.36002,35.45001,37.11002,35.78003,36.75998,35.78003z"/><path class="st1" d="M22.39999,35.86509V36.32c0,0.71,0.58,1.29,1.29,1.29h0.93c0.71,0,1.29-0.58,1.29-1.29v-0.43993"/><path class="st1" d="M21.00458,13.27578c-1.74433,0.9948-3.03389,2.64047-3.76966,4.84763"/><line class="st1" x1="16.98094" x2="16.84722" y1="20.13664" y2="21.16766"/></g></g></svg>


//this is notifcation panel DIV
                <div class="notificationPanel">
                    this should be full screen
                </div>




            </div>
            <div class="profilePicDrop">
                <img src="./img/sky-night-space-trees%20(4).jpeg" alt="">
                <div class="getDisplayNone dropDown">

                    <a href="#">vdvdv</a>


                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</header>




</body>
</html>
```

Homepage.scss

```
 @import "utils/_reset";
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400');
    @import "utils/_variables";

    body{
      background: #EEEEEE;

    }
    header{
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      height:50px;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      right: 0;
      background: #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 0px 11px 32px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);

      .innerwrapper{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        height: 50px;
        width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto;






      }

      h1{
        color: #393e46;

        font-family: $FontStyle;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 1.5px;
        font-weight: 400;
        a{
          padding: 5px;
          border: 1px solid #393e46;
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #393e46;
          font-size: 13px;
          transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;

          &:hover{
            background:#393e46 ;
            color: #ffffff;
          }

        }




      }
      .otherOptions{
        margin-left: auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;






        .profilePicDrop{
          width: 25px;
          height:25px;

          position: relative;
          margin-left: 12px;




          img{
            width: 25px;
            height:25px;

            border-radius: 50px;

          }

          .dropDown{
            width: 150px;
            height:150px;
            background: #ffffff;
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top:35px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);



          }
        }

      }




    }

    .getDisplayNone{
      display: none;
    }

    .getDropMenuIn{

      animation: PopIn;
      animation-duration: 0.3s;

      animation-fill-mode: forwards;




    }
    .getOutDropMenu{
      animation: PopOut;
      animation-duration: .3s;

      animation-fill-mode: forwards;







    }


    .notificationdiv{

      margin-top: 5px;
      position: relative;


      svg{
        width: 30px;
        height:30px;


      }

      .notifyCoun{
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #E74C3C;
        width: 17.5px;

        height:17.5px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 14px 0px rgba(231,77,60,0.3);

        p{
          font-size: 12px;

          font-family: $FontStyle;
          color: #ffffff;
          font-weight: 300;



        }


      }

      &:hover{
        cursor: pointer;

      }

    }

//this is notification panel css
    .notificationPanel{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;

      background: #ffffff;
      width: 100%;




    }
    @keyframes PopIn {
      from{
        transform: scale(0.8);
        opacity: 0.5;

      transform-origin: 150px -5px;

      }to{
           transform: scale(1);
           opacity: 1;
           visibility: visible;



         }
    }
    @keyframes PopOut {
      from{

        opacity: 1;




      }to{
           opacity: 0.1;
           visibility: hidden;
           transform: scale(0.5);
           transform-origin: 150px -5px;





         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `position: relative` from your `.notificationdiv`. Because your absolute element will take 100% of his first relative parent.

https://codepen.io/OliviaPaquay/pen/mwbQEj Demo here, remove line 10.